# Unable to upgrade python six package in mac osx 10.10.2

Tags: python, macos, pip, six

I am trying to install latest version of six python package but I have following issues. Can't get rid of six 1.4.1 in mac OSX 10.10.2

```
sudo pip install six --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

pip search six
six - Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
INSTALLED: 1.9.0 (latest)

python -c "import six; print six.version"
1.4.1

which -a python
/usr/bin/python
which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

What is wrong here? Can't upgrade six!

Comment: Try uninstalling six: `pip uninstall six`.  Then do an install.

Comment: It seems as if `python` and `pip` do not belong to the same interpreter. Try `python -m pip install --upgrade six` instead. If this does not help consider adding the output of `which -a python` and `which -a pip` to your question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, I am not in virtualenv.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I largely switched to Node and NPM. These sick issues with Python dependencies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mac OS X's default python is installed as a framework.
Under the framework directory, there is an 'Extras' directory and `six` package is already placed there.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py`

According to the description (https://github.com/MacPython/wiki/wiki/Which-Python), `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras` is listed before `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` in module search path.
This means all packages already exists in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras` can't upgrade.

Maybe you should install python manually and not to use default python.

Comment: Another solution is setting `PYTHONPATH` like `export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. All paths specified in `PYTHONPATH` is high priority than OS X framework python libraries.

Comment: This worked for me: 
python -m pip install --upgrade six

Comment: My six wouldn't update because the Caches library in my Library did not have the right permissions/ownership (according to pip). @roopalgarg 's solution worked for me too (osx 10.11). Thanks!

Comment: this didn't work for me.. still getting the same error, can't upgrade the framework packages.  As a newbie, would i find somewhere a step by step work around for this ? i have python 3 installed as well as python 2. could that be a problem ? i m on mac os x 10.11.1

Answer (score 24):

I resolved the problem by the following method.

1. Download the six-1.10.0.tar.gz package
2. Use this command to install it.

`python setup.py install`

This works because it installs the new version of six to **/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/** which is searched before **/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/**

Comment: Cleanest solution if you want to leave the OS X python intact.

Comment: This should have been the best answer. Quick. 

Six Package 1.11.0 link=> [http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/basic/ch06s08.html]

Answer (score 17):

Your `pip` binary belongs to `/usr/local/bin/python`, whereas `python` points to `/usr/bin/python`. As a consequence

```
pip install --upgrade six
```

will install to `/usr/local/bin/python`.

The command below will make sure that the right version of pip is used:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade six
```

Comment: your answer helped me. I'm using Mac os x 10.10.5

Comment: i did the change, but still getting the same error message..  i m on 10.11.1

Comment: @Raghav, it's probably best if you document exactly what you did and the errors you get and then start a new question that links to my answer.

Comment: Trying to upgrade six is the objective, apparently, its part of the system packages, here's the message
----------------------------------
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/98/kcksn_cn7619mkjsmlgqt8lc0000gn/T/pip-mSyToD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
--------------
i have the same spec, --->$ which -a pip
==>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip
===>/usr/local/bin/pip
--->$ which -a python
===>/usr/bin/python

Answer (score 16):

For me, just using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) fixed everything.

```
brew install python
```

Answer (score 16):

What worked for me was to use `easy_install` instead of `pip`.

```
easy_install -U six
```

Easy_install managed to upgrade the package even when pip failed.

Comment: Amazing. Things like this make me wonder why I use computers for anything. What's so wrong with pen and paper?

Comment: I think this is what worked for me in MacOS 10.13.3 however it didn't take effect immediately, I think I just had to restart the terminal. six 1.4.0 is still in the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python` dir though, inactive.

Comment: I ended up installing what I was ultimately trying to install that depended on six (awscli) with easy_install as well. Seems like pip install might be broken on Mac OS X

Answer (score 4):

I came across this exact issue when using pip to install the openstack client. My fix was to use easy_install instead of pip, as it utilizes `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` for module installation instead of the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras`. If this workaround is not an option for you, then I can confirm that @Masakazu Matsushita has the correct workaround of setting `PYTHONPATH` to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. To implement that workaround, add this line:

```
export PYTHON_PATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

to your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` (if its a GUI Python application that you are trying to install).

Comment: Wait, is it PYTHONPATH or PYTHON_PATH?

Answer (score 3):

**Try these steps**

1. Reinstall python using brew

   `$ brew install python`
2. Resolve missing symlink problem

   `$ brew link --overwrite python`
3. Reboot system or run

   `$ hash -r python`

Answer (score 3):

Try with pip2 its work for me
    pip2 install -U six

Answer (score 1):

While one or another of the above solutions may work for you, I think it's important to understand what is going on and what are the options that you have. I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223163/22890) (rather lengthy) description to be very useful: it starts with outlining the options and only then suggests solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the problem for me was that I was using the IPython shell.

`which ipython` returned `/usr/local/bin/ipython` and upon inspection this file declared at the top `#!/usr/bin/python`, which seemed to be circumventing all my best efforts to use the correct python location.

Simply changing this line `#!/usr/local/bin/python` to point to the correct python version then meant IPython used the correct `six` module.