# Installing Tweepy with pip

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I am trying to install tweepy with the pip command

```
pip install tweepy
```

however it is coming up with the error

```
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
...
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/zt/c358wgd9255dc9xc2c4s7p9c0000gn/T/pip-odKEwd-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I am on a mac running OSX 10.12

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think the error can be resolved by executing `pip install scrape --upgrade --ignore-installed six` see: [On OS X El Capitan I can not upgrade a python package dependent on the six compatibility utilities NOR can I remove six](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185147/on-os-x-el-capitan-i-can-not-upgrade-a-python-package-dependent-on-the-six-compa)

Comment: That still gives an OSError.

Comment: what about `pip install tweepy --ignore-installed six`? Still `OSError`?

Comment: By the way, based on your Error, I'm just relaying suggestions from https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165

Comment: No it worked. Thank you, but one final thing. Can you briefly explain the difference? And maybe what caused the OSError

Comment: Oh Thank you.  @downshift

Comment: it seems the reason for the error is a conflict between the pre-installed `six` package that is shipped with OSX 10.12, and the `tweepy` package attempts to uninstall that OSX pre-installed `six` version, but the OS reports to python that it's not permitted to uninstall it. Hope it helps, glad you got it fixed, cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged python-3.x my guess is that you also have python 3 installed and want to use that instead. The `pip` command by default, is used to install package for `python-2.7` which is included with mac, but you do not have permission to modify library `six` for the built in python 2. So you should type this instead for python 3 `pip`:

```
pip3 install tweepy
```

if you are actually trying to install tweepy to python 2, then you should include the option `--ignore-installed six` which is required when installing packages that needs `six` since the included `six` module doesn't work fluently. So you should type the command which ignores the included `six` and install a new one overriding it:

```
pip install tweepy --ignore-installed six
```

Comment: Didn't work until I added sudo. sudo pip3 install tweepy