# Trouble installing Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to install tweepy API, working on Mac OS with Python 3, by using the following command:

```
$ pip install tweepy
```

However, when I do so, it starts working fine until an error at the end appears. At that moment, it fails to download properly. I do not understand quite the error, which is shown below.

```
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: six, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, tweepy
Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we     cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Therefore, Tweepy does not install properly because of it. Do I need to download Nose and Tornado? I am also at a loss to understand what 'six' is. I am fairly new to this and, furthermore, I do not have a whole lot of experience working with the command line.

EDIT:: Thank you for question edits to make it more readable.

Comment: Please add error message + traceback

Comment: Maybe try `pip3 install tweepy`, (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939111/installing-tweepy-with-pip). on Mac OS, the `pip` command usually installs packages for the system's `python` (on my mac is `Python 2.7.10`) that is pre-installed for the operating system function properly. instead, `pip3` should be used to target the `python3` environment.