# Import error on 'from six import raise_from'

Tags: python, six

I'm trying to use the gmusicapi(https://github.com/simon-weber/gmusicapi). However when I try the following line:

```
from gmusicapi import Webclient
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gmusicapi-10.0.2rc1-py2.7.egg/gmusicapi/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from gmusicapi.clients import Webclient, Musicmanager, Mobileclient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gmusicapi-10.0.2rc1-py2.7.egg/gmusicapi/clients/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gmusicapi.clients.webclient import Webclient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gmusicapi-10.0.2rc1-py2.7.egg/gmusicapi/clients/webclient.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gmusicapi.protocol import webclient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gmusicapi-10.0.2rc1-py2.7.egg/gmusicapi/protocol/webclient.py", line 6, in <module>
    from six import raise_from
ImportError: cannot import name raise_from
```

I'm not sure why I am unable to import raise_from.

I'm running python2.7.6 with six version at 1.5.2

Comment: What version of `six` do you have?  `import six; print(six.__version__)`

Comment: six version is 1.5.2

Comment: I'm on `1.10.0` so you're a good number of revisions behind.  You aren't using OS-X by any chance are you?  The default `six` shipped with `OS-X` is horribly outdated ...

Comment: If you are on OS-X, you might try one of the suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29485741/748858) to update `six`.

Comment: That may be it, I'll try updating it and see if it works. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works fine for me. And I have python 2.7.5.

Try this `pip install --upgrade six`

Comment: That worked. I ran in to an issue where pip wouldn't upgrade because the previous version wasn't being deleted (https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2964). Ended up removing the previous six files manually (rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six-1.5.2.egg-info) and then upgraded.